# Are these questions the same?

Tags: discussion, closing

I'm having a hard time distinguishing the differences between the two, but since both are sufficiently answered,  I don't know what to do.

Are these two questions dupes of each other?

1. [When does the weekly drop count reset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322/when-does-the-weekly-drop-count-reset)
2. [What is the limit on finding items in TF2? How can I tell if I have hit this?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25306/what-is-the-limit-on-finding-items-in-tf2-how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-hit-this)

Answer (score 4):

## No, they are not

Now, assuming both are up to date, these questions are fully valid and address distinctly different details - even though they could theoretically be merged into one combined question about the nature of the drop limit.

[When does the weekly drop count reset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322/when-does-the-weekly-drop-count-reset) asks for *when* it takes place, while [What is the limit on finding items in TF2? How can I tell if I have hit this?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25306/what-is-the-limit-on-finding-items-in-tf2-how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-hit-this) asks for the *amount*.

Now, as I said, they do address the same base topic: The drop limit. Merging them would, however, probably be more detrimental to the quality than leaving them be and perhaps referencing one another. Why? Because both have good answers and it may not be *actually necessary* to read information about both the *time* and the *amount* - as seen by the fact that these distinct questions exist to begin with.

Comment: +1 [Just like here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6757/are-these-two-questions-similar-duplicates/6766#6766), they could have probably worked just fine as one question since they both address the drop limit, but they are indeed distinct questions. No need to force them together.